# How to delete all the files in recycle bin using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following code in vb.net for deleting the contents of the recycle bin:

```
 Sub DeleteFilesFromRecycleBin(Folder As String)
    If Directory.Exists(Folder) Then
        For Each _file As String In Directory.GetFiles(Folder)

            File.Delete(_file)

        Next
        For Each _folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Folder)

            DeleteFilesFromRecycleBin(_folder)
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Function call statement: DeleteFilesFromRecycleBin("C:\$Recycle.Bin")

Now the main problem is that whenever I call the function for C drive, it works and removes all the files deleted from C drive. But, whenever I use the same function for deleting the files which were deleted from D drive using the function call statement:  DeleteFilesFromRecycleBin("D:\$Recycle.Bin"), I get an error message saying: “Access to the path 'D:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-3547970170-1955488480-3058331685-1004' is denied”. I get the same error message when I do the same with E drive. I am already logged in as an administrator. Please help me figure out the problem.

Comment: Logging in as Administrator might not help - you need to run your application as Administrator.  Search SO for 'elevated privileges'.

Answer (score 3):

The directory is hidden in Windows Explorer on purpose; it's internal to how the recycle bin works (for example, you can recycle files with the same name from different directories). The "Empty Recyle Bin" button in Explorer may just empty `D:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-3547970170-1955488480-3058331685-1004` but that's not your concern.

You will have to use unmanaged code (Windows shell) because this is a *system level* function which the .NET framework does not wrap (manage):

```
Private Declare Function SHEmptyRecycleBin Lib "shell32.dll" Alias
"SHEmptyRecycleBinA" (ByVal hWnd As Int32, ByVal pszRootPath As String,
ByVal dwFlags As Int32) As Int32
Private Declare Function SHUpdateRecycleBinIcon Lib "shell32.dll" () As
Int32

Private Const SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION = &H1
Private Const SHERB_NOPROGRESSUI = &H2
Private Const SHERB_NOSOUND = &H4

Private Sub EmptyRecycleBin()
    SHEmptyRecycleBin(Me.Handle.ToInt32, "", SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION + SHERB_NOSOUND)
    SHUpdateRecycleBinIcon()
End Sub
```

Source:

http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/509609-empty-recycle-bin-vb-net-code "Empty Recycle bin - VB.NET code"

In general it is bad to use unmanaged code for reliability reasons (.NET can't protect you) and because if you ever want to run your program on a different platform (for example, via Mono), you'll probably have a hard time - `shell32.dll` is Windows only.